# How to effectively deal with Imposter Syndrome and feelings of inadequacy: "I've somehow convinced everyone that I'm actually good at this"

Tags: graduate-school, emotional-responses

[Imposter syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome) is a psychological phenomenon wherein an individual is convinced that they do not deserve the success that they have achieved despite (perhaps extensive) empirical evidence to the contrary.  Some people with imposter syndrome doubt their own ability level. For me, this usually manifests in the thought:

> **I've somehow convinced everyone into believing that I'm actually good at this.**

followed by the horrifying notion that eventually I'll be found out and my world will collapse.

I believe that the imposter syndrome is not uncommon in academia. I'm interested to know how other people here have experienced and dealt with it.

> In particular, I'm looking for **actual tactics** that someone might
> use to combat imposter syndrome.

---

*Why I asked this question:*

Beyond the obvious reason that this is something I have struggled with for many years and only recently gotten a handle on myself, there's also some evidence that merely realizing that other people experience imposter syndrome helps fellow imposters. As a grad student, I've managed to meet a fair number of people who are in their own struggles with imposter syndrome; however, the tactics and self-trickery that have helped me don't always speak to them and perhaps someone else's methods might.

Comment: Of course one manifestation of imposter syndrome is that I'm unwilling to answer this question for being called out as the one person for whom imposter syndrome is NOT imaginary.

Comment: There is a TED talk about this exact subject, titled "Fake it until you become it"

Comment: Remember that *this is hard*. Everyone is bad at *this*.You're *not good* at this, your just *less bad* at this than everyone else!

Comment: I agree with recursion.ninja. Although openly expressing it to people who don't have the same kind of humour could make you sound quite negativist, depressed or even misanthropic.

Comment: I'm surprised that Dunning-Kruger effect (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) hasn't been mentioned.

Comment: See also this recent article (https://80000hours.org/2022/04/imposter-syndrome/) over on 80000 Hours.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

I found two practices helped me a lot:

- **Reinforce what you know**. The biggest problem with being an academic surrounded by other academics is that you're constantly being confronted by things you don't know. Even worse, it often seems like everyone else knows something that you don't know.

  You don't need me to tell you how demoralizing that is. The fight is to go back and review what you *do* know, and reinforce your expertise in your subject area. Most academics are polyglots; choose some random thing you've studied, learned, or even just considered previously, and review it every now and then. It'll help you view the progress you're making.
- **Engage non-academics**. You don't realize how much you know until you talk to the other 99.99% of people who don't know what you know. (Confusing sentence...) Write blogs, offer to give visiting lectures at a school or workplace, work as an intern or consultant in industry, champion a political cause related to your research. There are so many ways you can make use of your knowledge, and doing so will definitely help massage your ego which has been bruised by many semesters of feeling inadequate.

Comment: Ref. "engage non-academics": pick a SE site of your area and help those who know less than you. :-)

Comment: Returning a few years later: I can confirm that (for some) this feeling never goes away, no matter how much external validation you receive. Don't let the feeling get in the way of doing awesome things.

Comment: I was about to write what @eykanal just wrote in this comment.  Perhaps the best way to feel like less of an impostor is to be clinically narcissistic, but that's probably not something you could change without gene therapy or experimental drugs or something

Answer (score 105):

It's hard to even think of a time when I didn't feel like an imposter. I would tell myself constantly that I was succeeding only due to luck, or having spent more time working as opposed to having any actual ability, or the fact that as an international student I had a very different background from my peers and therefore had an unfair advantage, and so on. At some point in graduate school when I came across the phrase 'imposter syndrome' I finally realized that I am not alone and started to get over it, to some extent.

Here are some things that have helped:

1. **Knowing that this is a real thing (I'm not alone!)** The mere fact that there is a name for what I was feeling was a big deal. Imposter syndrome is a documented phenomenon that many people have to deal with. I sometimes go back to the wikipedia page just to remind myself of this.
2. **Knowing that several bigger, brighter academics have felt (or feel) similarly inadequate on occasion**. It's easy to convince oneself that while imposter syndrome is common among grad students, maybe only the 'non-imposters' actually go on to succeed - knowing that even the academic superstars I look up to sometimes doubt themselves helps to remind me that this is false.
3. **Forcing myself to look at the empirical data.** I imagine some other grad student, with exactly the same achievements as mine and ask myself what I think about them.

However, honestly, this is very much work-in-progress for me.

Comment: "The mere fact that there is a name for what I was feeling was a big deal."- aptly said. *thumbs up*

Comment: Also, honestly, you just have to _keep trying things_.  Everyone has felt like this, and it's tempting to wishfully think some magical "strategy" is going to cure all pain or some other person would magically "just know it because they're smarter than you," but the way those other people "just know it" is simply that they've tried that particular thing

Comment: I am confused that this answer was posted almost simultaneously with the question. It seems like the whole thread was, perhaps, a chance by the OP to opine on this topic.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @DavidWhite thanks for your comment! I posted a link above to the Stackexchange FAQ about self-answers.

Comment: Also: “To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.” From the Stackexchange blog https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 73):

## The Harsh Reality: They Do Exist

Before I met my roommate, I thought that I was one of the most intelligent people that I've ever met, pretentious, I know, but just being honest.  When the material was upper-level undergrad or graduate level, I studied, but even at a top tier university, I got amazing grades with much less effort than most of my peers, which was convenient but in an odd way depressing and isolating; however, my grades dramatically changed after a lot of personal losses (this is relevant, see below).

I'm sure a lot of us are in awe of well renowned professors--if you're an academic, they're like rock stars, at least to me they are.  I've always looked up to these people, they make me feel like there's a place for me in this world.  Anyway, as a result of being extraordinarily depressed, I lost almost all of my confidence.  Unfortunately for me, this was when I met my (now) roommate, which made me feel so much worse.

There are people who say that they don't study when they really do.  There are people who appear to be really smart when they're really not.  There's a major difference between knowing a lot of facts and actually being intelligent.  My roommate is quite literally the most brilliant person I've ever met, including several Nobel laureates.  After living with him, I discovered that he actually doesn't study, at least not like most people do.  He can read something once, at a ridiculously fast speed--quite literally he can read a full textbook page in under 20 seconds and comprehend everything.  This is not limited to any particular domain.  There are countless times that I have gone to him with high level mathematics problems from disciplines that he's not too familiar with, and he's able to not only understand everything almost immediately, but he can synthesize beautiful solutions and explain the concepts to me better than my professors who've been in the field for years.  I know it sounds unbelievable, but I assure you that it's true.

My roommate was a major stumbling block for me.  After meeting him, I began to doubt my intelligence even more.  If people like him exist, what the hell am I going to do?  How could I possibly compete with him?  I went to speak with a few of my professors to essentially ask them if they were like my roommate.  If they all were, then I knew that I had no place in the academia.  Fortunately, out of all of the professors that I talked to, every single one of them said that they struggled a lot.  While some of them knew one or two people like my roommate, they reassured me that not only did they put a ton of work in and struggle, but they also doubted themselves all the time, and most still do.

I guess what I am saying is that sometimes it can make sense to feel like an imposter.  Some people are just *geniuses*, and I do not use that term lightly.  In the end, 99% of the best of the best of the best still struggle a lot.  It's okay to struggle, it's good.  It means that you're learning.  For what it's worth, if you're accepted into a PhD program or lab or what have you, the admissions committee/PI made a conscious decision to say that they believe that you are good enough.  I don't care if you think that you got in because you knew someone, and that person recommended you.  (A) that happens all the time, and (B), they actually went out of their way to recommend you.  They put their reputation on the line for you.  They wouldn't do that unless they believed in you--these are really intelligent people, you didn't trick them.  Finally, for the people who only think that they got to where they are because of hard work and not natural intelligence, I say to you (A) that's probably not true (smart people tend to think that because they struggle with stuff and finally understand it, that everyone can and that's patently false) and (B) you're more likely to be successful than someone smarter who doesn't put in as much work.  Sorry for the really long answer, but I hope it helps someone.  It made me feel better just writing it.  Cheers!

**EDIT:**
One last thing, the more one travels down the rabbit hole, the more one realizes just how little they know.  This can lead people to question their intelligence.  It's pretty ironic, you're becoming more informed and because of it you feel less informed.  In this case, you just need to take a step back and realize that true mastery is impossible.  It should be a good feeling to learn that which one did not know before.  It's doesn't mean that you're stupid, it means you're getting smarter.  If you think that you know everything or even can know everything, **then** perhaps you are not that intelligent.

Comment: The story about your roommate makes me think "superman exists"

Comment: @AbrahamGuchi Yeah, he truly is an *academic superman*.  People don't believe me, then they meet him and they're like: "Oh my gosh, you really are the smartest person I've ever met."  He's very humble, though.

Comment: I would really like to meet your room mate one day

Comment: @user774025 Good luck.  He doesn't really leave our apartment.  He's a very special person...

Comment: As the old saying goes, "if you are the smartest person in the room, you are in the wrong room".

Comment: It took me till my early twenties to recognize that being of "above average intelligence" really just means you're smart enough to be painfully aware that you're trapped somewhere between being frustrated by the average person and not being able to hold a candle to the flame of the geniuses you encounter.

I've struggled to come to terms with it ever since.

Comment: I studied BA in Graphic Design first time round at uni and got so bored after I realized the main point of it was to 'sell things to people who don't want them' I didn't even bother finishing it. I left uni and got a proper job and realized I loved computers. I learned everything I could about them and am now getting top marks on an MSc in Comp. Sci (with no BSc). The point to this tanget? The more you enjoy what you do and the harder you work the more you will become like your roommate. Like everything else, the more you do something the easier it becomes: including learning stuff.

Comment: @Styne666 very true, I could put a ton of effort into studying things I like and consequently be IMHO quite good at them, (Maybe I am blowing my own trumpet here), But I find it difficult to give even more than an hr to learn things that I don't like. Forcing myself to do things I don't like makes me veer off into such qasi productive stuff like browsing Se sites like this, Some times it may even  lead me on

Comment: to totally unproductive things

Comment: What is your roommate doing today? Btw the more you struggle the more you value the end result.

Comment: The roommate might also get so used to having everything come easily that he can't deal with setbacks when he faces really really big problems.  There's a story that Von Neumann himself once spent his whole day doing some math and throwing all of the pages in the trash afterwards.  If it happened to John Von Neumann, who cares whether you have a roommate who can read really fast?  The point is that somehow you can succeed if you really put your mind to it

Comment: Come on @SteveP. don't keep us hanging here - what's the latest with the roommate?

Answer (score 51):

Personal take on this, or why I don't feel quite as much like an imposter these days.

I've spent years toiling away in the salt mines of my choice convinced that I was just scraping by at every stage that didn't involve a formal "exam" (I'm good at those). Certain that I was surrounded by my betters. Because I'm in big science I got to do this in settings that involved a lot of close work and socializing with my peers; I've worked closely enough with scores of people at various points on their career arcs to get to know our relative strengths and weakness.

And I've slowly come to a realization which has taken (some of) the pressure off:

> Yes, I suck and I'm really only good at a couple of the bits of this job and other people make me look like piker in almost everything involved in this work
>
> ... but ...
>
> with only a couple of exceptions<sup>1</sup> **they suck too**.
>
> I really am better than average (even among my peers) at a couple of things. They are not big flashy things, they don't draw the admiration of crowds, but they are things that need doing and I'm pretty good at them.

So, I've become content (at least some) to be a worker bee: I've got a part to play in this enterprise, I know how to do it and people will ask me to do it because in these little corners they are even worse.

---

<sup>1</sup> The only thing I can say about these folks is that they are few and far between and there aren't enough of them to keep me from getting work. And I try not to think about them. And I think I'll have another drink.

But it is inevitable for most of us. If you are N sigma above the norm, then there is one person who is N+2 sigma for every ten people like you. Unless you one of the ten smartest in the world there are going to be people who make you look like you can barely walk and chew gum at the same time. That is just the way it is.

Comment: This answer isn't *quite* as bleak as the Lego Grad Student, but it's close.

Answer (score 36):

As Aru Ray said, knowing that this is actually a quite common feeling is helpful in overcoming it. Ways you can achieve that include **discussing it with others**, including accomplished researchers, and reading about it. Here are a few texts and resources on the topic, which I recommend heartily to both students and faculty:

- A recent article in the [Chronicles of Higher Education](http://chronicle.com/article/An-Academic-With-Impostor/138231/), which sums it up nicely. And also, some reactions on the web: [1](http://www.hookandeye.ca/2013/04/academic-imposter-syndrome.html), [2](http://ianmilligan.ca/2013/04/16/an-aside-an-academic-with-imposter-syndrome/)
- A personal experience [is related here](http://thebluereview.org/impostor-syndrome-in-academia/)
- The [references over there](http://mentalfaculties.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/on-impostor-syndrome/) make for pretty good reading too…

Answer (score 19):

This question struck a nerve...I didn't know that this feeling is an actual diagnosable syndrome! As an undergrad who is attempting an ambitious course load, including research projects far beyond what most undergrads in my school tackle, I often struggle with feeling that the praise, recognition, and high grades I receive must be mere kindness on the part of the professors, who surely are just impressed by the amount of effort I put in! I **know** I am not a genius, so those who say I am must be mistaken.

Remembering what the famous inventor Thomas Edison said is always helpful when I begin to feel like an imposter. "Genius is 1% inspiration and 99% perspiration." Knowing that I have put in a large amount of 'perspiration', I realize that even if others are being generous in their applause, I have earned **most** of it through sheer hard work, and I can accept the rest of it being providence or luck or whatever it is to which you want to attribute unearned success.

In short, realizing that most success is due to hard work, and accepting that a small part of success will always be unpredictable and unearned has helped me deal with Imposter Syndrome. I realize that depending on the situation and the severity of your symptoms, this may be of no help at all...

Answer (score 10):

The way you have phrased your statement "I've cleverly fooled everyone into believing that I'm actually good at this." makes me think of two different situations.

The first is when you have low self-esteem and simply do not think you are worth much as a person. With low [self-esteem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-esteem) comes also low [self-confidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-confidence), which is a very common situation in academia -- I recognize it from myself. Self-esteem can be a sign of depression and can in such cases be medicated. Self-confidence is something one can build through positive feedback from others so that the value of ones work is seen. It is possible to have reasonably good self-confidence but still have poor self-esteem. In such cases you have to keep up a facade to seem confident although you do not feel as such.

The second case I think of is more of a psychological (permanent) condition, akin to [narcissism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissism) where you deliberately thrive from deceiving people that you are more than you really are. In such cases you thrive to fool other into thinking something and the goal is the manipulation and nothing about the truth. I think we can see some of this as well (of course since it is a human aspect) in persons who try to cheat more or less successfully. I would not be surprised if some of the more famous scientific cheats suffer from this affliction although peer pressure could certainly play a role.

So in the end, regardless of type, you will find these feelings/afflictions because they are all part of the human psyche and becomes a burden if not in balance.

Comment: I agree that the phrasing of the question was somewhat ambiguous and I've changed it to reflect the question better.

Comment: However, I'm not certain that this answers the question. For example, you say that 'Self-confidence is something one can build through positive feedback from others so that the value of ones work is seen', but imposter syndrome is exactly when positive feedback is deemed meaningless by the 'sufferer'.

Answer (score 10):

Having struggled with imposter syndrome since what feels like my birth ("How have I fooled everyone into believing I deserve to exist and participate in society?!"), I frequently revisit these answers for a moral boost, especially during conferences, where I fear the concentration of experts looking at my work all at once will somehow trigger my pending demise. (Thankfully, so far, that hasn't happened; quite often, the opposite happens, and I make friends who want to talk more about our mutual interests.)

Since it wasn't mentioned in any of the other answers, I wanted to add something I've discovered for myself.

It's very important to have a life outside of work.  This is true for any job, but especially a career in academia, where the work culture can often feel cultish.  I've found that it's especially important to have self-improvement goals completely unrelated to my research: training for a 5k, meditating 10 minutes a day, learning a language, forcing myself to break a social rule/take a risk/look stupid/get rejected at least once a day.  (The latter is to help combat my OCD, which often triggers imposter moments, through a kind of exposure therapy.)

Investing in other people-- family, friends, scuba diving club, neighborhood clean-up groups-- is also absolutely essential.  Anxiety (a sinister companion of imposter syndrome) inherently causes the sufferer to focus on themself and their safety and their needs, often at the expense of others' well-being.  So it is also essential to make time for these other people-- e.g., by banning work outside of the lab, avoiding checking work e-mail on evenings and weekends, scheduling appointments and holding them sacred.

The consequence of having non-work related self-improvement goals and people to invest in is that my identity is less wrapped up in my "success" as a researcher. It depends more on who I am holistically as a person, as well as the joy and appreciation I experience from living live more fully in community with others.

Answer (score 4):

The more productive question may be, "Is the present situation better with me or without me?"  If you believe your participation is actually detrimental, step aside... but in most cases you'll realize that, whether or not you're the Platonic Ideal of whatever you're striving to be, the situation is still better with you there making that effort.

In other words, worry more about the world and less about yourself.  Like paranoia, self-doubt is itself inherently somewhat narcissistic.

Or to put it another way: That which we would become we must first impersonate.  Viewed in that light imposture isn't necessarily such a bad thing.  We all have to fake it till we make it.  And a robust appreciation of our ignorance is the foundation of wisdom.

Comment: I must disagree with everything in this answer, hence the downvote. Regardless of whether you think you contribute to the present situation doesn't matter, Worry about yourself, the world will get on just fine. FITYMIT only works for certain viewers, and if you are already not happy faking it, then it's not going to help. I hold that 1) I am supremely unimportant but 2) everybody else is supremely unimportant too. Therefore, I am just as important as the next person, just as worthy of the attention and praise that arrives at their door.