# Problems with supervisor – Should I listen to myself or just follow him?

Tags: phd, advisor

I started a PhD in September of the last year at a European university in the field of engineering. I was very enthusiastic about it because I really worked hard to obtain this opportunity and I won three positions in total (the one I choose in the end and other two).
The project where I am now looked amazing, there were also the possibility to go in another country to do some experiments and it was together with other industries and university. I enjoy the spirit of "science is done together" and so I believed that here I could find my happiness.

I started. I found troubles in understanding the content of the papers I was reading. This because I am a civil engineer and the project is more in the field of mechanical/material engineering. It took me a while to really start to understand also the language of my other colleagues and I am still working on that. I realized that my supervisor has a hands-off approach, so he does not have the expertise in my field. I started to feel a little bit alone, doubting that I could really do something good without a real technical feedback. I talked with a friend who is doing a postdoc and he told me that this situation is quite normal and the really valuable skills that matter are the ability to work alone and independently. I understand that, but honestly it is far from the motivation that I have to do a PhD: I do not do it to become a professor; I do not do it to become a manager; I just want to give a little contribution to science, and I do not think that as a young PhD student, I am able to understand everything without support.

My supervisor cares about documenting everything that is done and about writing. He is obsessed with me to writing a perfect report each time. I understand that, on the long run, this is important because I can forget the details, but I have to say that it stresses me a lot: I would like to spend more time doing something good rather than writing every single detail. This approach is due also to his lack of knowledge, since he needs me to explain everything I do.

During last month our relationship became worse: He says that I have problem in understanding (in the civil field), and honestly I do not think so. I am just not very good in the writing part, because I am not used to write a lot and I also do not really like it. There are some postdocs in the mechanical department working in my field, and I tried to ask my supervisor if I could collaborate with them, but he denied this in a kind way. He said that we are independent and we “do not need them”. However, I need them. I need some support during this initial period of the PhD.

Some weeks ago I asked the head of the department if I could get some support because of the interdisciplinary nature of my PhD and during the meeting he said yes. He then completely changed in a subsequent meeting with my supervisor and me: He changed his mind and both of them had my last report printed. They pointed out every mistake. For example, in a table there was a typo because I had missed a zero in a number. Maybe I am superficial, but why is doing a mistake is so serious? Why do they have to make me feel not good enough because my report is not perfect? My supervisor is lacking in a lot of things, but he will be always right.
In the end of the meeting, they told me that I should be “more critical” but they believe in me. Honestly I do not believe in these words from my supervisor. It is not that he tells me what I did wrong, it is that sometimes I find him mean in the way he tells me things.

I have applied for other projects. I won a position in the UK one week ago, in a good university, and I was shortlisted two times in another very good university in Europe. The position in UK is sure, while the other one no. I would like to go, but I feel bad about myself. What if is it me? What if I am not able to pursue a PhD? Talking with other students in the departement, I found out that also other students had problems with him and some of them have left. Two who stayed say that they hope I will make the right decision so I will not feel bad like them in the following years.

How can I approach this situation?

Comment: Hello there und nice to see you in this forum! This seems like a good question, but it is too long and not good formatted. Also you should ask a clear question, not for comments. Maybe you can refine the question in this way? This would br nice, otherwise we should not answer it. I hope you enjoy your stay!

Comment: _in a table there was a typo because I missed one zero in a number and so the measurement was wrong_ is not serious? In the real world you could be fired right on the spot.for this.

Comment: @scaaahu: *In the real world you could be fired right on the spot.for this.* – Depending on your country’s labour laws, you can be fired for anything. However, any reasonable company will have better ways to avoid errors in critical data digitalisation than fear of being fired. For example, if critical data really has to be digitialised by hand, have at least two different people digitalise it independently.

Comment: You do not like to write -but much of academia is precisely about communication. You need to learn to write well and communicate well. Errors: there are subtle, forgivable errors that happen. However, if you make them regularly, it means that your supervisor has to check everything in detail and cannot trust what you say. A supervisor needs to be able to trust his student that they invest attention to detail and do not make many errors, and, if they make errors, that they capture them quickly and put measures in place to mitigate them or avoid them next time. So, what is your precise question?

Comment: @scaaahu: This may be, but this then seems to be a horrible company nobody should want to work for anyways. Mistakes can happen - and this company has no better process to prevent them than to let it happen and fire the person on the spot?! Horrible. Which country?

Comment: "Missed a zero in a number"  I once had a student complaining that gave zero points on an answer that was wrong by a factor 1000. I offered 0.001 points. Or, yet another analogy, would you be upset if your salary is missing one of its zeros (or any other digit) before the comma?

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX: I do not understand this sarcasm. I asked for opinion because I am not sure of my approach, and I think my supervisor has his own reasons. However, I don't feel I am working for a company, I am sorry.

Comment: @Elen: no sarcasm here. The student fundametally did not understand that having the correct digits in the correct order, but the comma in the wrong place is a *serious* mistake. My example with your wage was meant to make you aware that you probably wouldn't think it negligible if the university wires you 137.49 € instead of the 1370.49 € you should get. But that is actually much *less* serious than the potential consequences of me (or my student) being wrong about an order of magnitude in our chemical labwork or you as civil engineer being wrong about the payload of a bridge: those may have

Comment: ... irreversible consequences. I do see one potential source of misunderstanding between you and your supervisor here: you write that you need supervision which the supervisor is not giving. The supervisor may be looking at you as a fully qualified professional in engineering. I.e. you are not only *allowed* to, say, construct bridges or machinery that has similar safety requirements but you are actually expected to work with the care that is necessary for someone potentially entrusted with such work. "Hands-off approach" and supervisor+dean pointing out that mistake as serious are consistent

Comment: ... with such a misunderstanding.

Comment: @Elen, when I was a fresh PhD student, I had the same feeling. Until my professor told me when I said I did not [yet] feel qualified for something: "You are a fully qualified professional since your Diplom [Master] - with all the rights and duties." - which got me thinking... Legally, my PhD does not allow me to do anything that I wasn't allowed to do after my Diplom. Of course you are not experienced yet - but you should be professional.

Comment: @cbeleites unhappy with SX: I am not saying I have the right to be unfocused, but I think I do have the right to have doubts and to do mistake not knowing how to conduct research, because it is not easy. In this moment for example, I would like to write an email to my supervisor with my ideas about some experiments we did, but I am too afraid of his reaction. I feel judged, I do not think this should be the feeling when you are doing a PhD.

Comment: Partially a duplicate of: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11765/ive-somehow-convinced-everyone-that-im-actually-good-at-this-how-to-effect

Answer (score 4):

If you're unhappy where you are and aren't getting support even though you've asked for it, and you've been offered a position elsewhere, I think you know logically what you should do. You should take that new position and hand in your notice to your current supervisor as soon as you can. Make a clean break of it and try to have some time off before starting the new project.

That's the logical thing to do. Emotionally, however, it's not so easy. You've spent a lot of time on your current project and worked hard, with little help, in an unfamiliar field. But don't fall foul of the sunk-cost fallacy: the belief that it's worth continuing to invest in something that's giving you no return, just because you already heavily invested in it. It very often isn't.

Finally, while you say you don't enjoy writing, the ability to write clearly and accurately is really important in research. Having very good written English is a must if you want to complete a PhD in the UK. The sooner you accept this, the better. Learning to critcally read and edit your own work is something your department or university can help you with; at my institution there is an "academic skills" office that provide help with writing, presentation skills etc to anyone who needs it. I recommend you seek out such help wherever you end up. Hopefully the more you write, the more you will come to enjoy it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I am aware about the writing part and I also do not feel strong about it. I know it is logical to think to leave, but it is like I am not ready to leave this place, because beside my supervisor, I have a really good relationship with the other people and I also do not know how it will be in the new place. I have no guarantee it is gonna be better.

Comment: I understand your point, but you have to answer this question: would you see yourself successful if you continue with the current supervisor, it seems people left the lab because of him. The most important question: have you asked about the other supervisor in UK?

Comment: @Erik No, I do not see myself happy working with him and if I had the chance, I would change supervisor. I had the chance to talk with the supervisor in the UK and he seems really nice and he is an expert in his field. We wrote a proposal together and even if I did mistakes in that text, he was very supportive and he was aware of the effort that I made to write it. I really appreciate this kind of behavior from a supervisor, because I can learn without feeling terrible. However I do not know him well, so this could be a wrong impression.

Comment: @Elen, I understand. First of all, you are in Europe, so I assume you hired on a project and probably you get funded through the current supervisor. For UK supervisor, have you asked the students working on the lab, alumni? I know the situation is hard when you still working with current supervisor, but do you have other options than UK to consider?

Comment: @Erik No, but it's a good idea to ask them. I have other two possibilities but both of them are not sure, since there is a selection process that is "on hold" for the pandemic. For one of them I visited the lab and the campus, since the professor invited me to join his group for a day. I had good conversations with the professor, he seems amazing and a highly intelligent person.

Answer (score 0):

Many issues mentioned are common to early stage PhD students and supervisors (should) work to improve, but a change in environment/field is unlikely to do so for most of them. Adjusting to a new field is challenging and needs patience, and the OP's attitude on that is natural (also and an academic looking for a PhD student will naturally appear affable). If the OP thinks that it is not possible to work with that supervisor (and a match of personalities makes a PhD much easier) then there is only one thing to do. However, the situation does not sound to be at a breaking point. Nothing of what I read struck me as unreasonable or malicious, and most of the following issues are unlikely to be improved by flying away from them.

> I would like to spend more time doing something good rather than
>   writing every single detail.

Doing something good often **IS** writing every single detail. In may ways, this is quintessencial science. If a single detail is missing someone else may not be able to reproduce the results or apply the method correctly. This is one of the main differences between writing a PhD and an academic paper or business report. The latter two are often on a "need to know" basis or assume the reader knows too much.

> This approach is due also to his lack of knowledge, since he needs me
>   to explain everything I do.

A PhD student worth his/her salt will know more about the PhD than the supervisor in the second half of it. Also, the supervisor is probably checking the OP's knowledge and scientific rigour, which can be done without being an expert on that field.

> For example, in a table there was a typo because I had missed a zero
>   in a number. Maybe I am superficial, but why is doing a mistake is so
>   serious?

An example of rigour. A typo in a PhD report/ meeting is not serious, a typo in an important presentation/ work report is very serious, the same mistake in the code/ practical application can be disastrous. This should not need explanation, and, at the very least, may make someone appear unreliable. All steps to avoid mistakes must be taken, regardless of consequences.

> There are some postdocs in the mechanical department working in my
>   field, and I tried to ask my supervisor if I could collaborate with
>   them, but he denied this in a kind way. However, I need them. I need
>   some support during this initial period of the PhD.

This, like the previous quote, indicates the OP's insecurity, which is natural for an early stage PhD student. A PhD, in many ways, is a long string of corrected mistakes and everyone needs to accept and overcome it - constant self-checking is imperative. I also agree with the supervisor's answer that the OP does not need them. A good solution is to attend some Masters classes on certain topics, which can be arranged with a polite email to the module leader. Also, senior academics who teach those classes are often willing to have a long meeting and explain things to a PhD student. A PhD student "needing" others is the opposite of the core of a PhD: independent learning and working. When someone achieves that skill, confidence and attitude, normally towards the end of the PhD, then student collaborations can be fruitful subject to departmental culture. Earlier than that, they can often be hugely detrimental, as it leads to delays, tensions, stress and people feeling/ treated as they cannot carry their own weight.

What I wrote on support obviously does not apply to personal relations, emotional support etc and the OP should absolutely avoid being isolated.